# Why this code is not working in wordpress page?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Hi this is my code which I am writing wordpress text editor. The code works perfectly when written in JSfiddle but does not work in the wordpress.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="box"></div>
<div id="target"></div>
<style>
#box{ 
height: 20px;
width:20px; 
background-color:red;
}
#target{ 
height: 50px;
width: 50px; 
border: 1px solid red;
float:right;
}
#target.twinkle{ 

border: 5px solid green;
}
</style>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#box").draggable();
$("#target").droppable({
 drop: function( event, ui ) {
   $( this )
      .addClass( "twinkle" ).html("dropped");

  }
});
});
</script>
```

The draggable works but when dropped on the target it does not add the class.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want to add class to the droppable? because that's what your code does

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/G65uV/2/ what do you want to happen

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of jQuery?

Comment: @ArunPJohny : The same code when written in wordpress editor doesnt work. The #box is draggable but when it is dropped over the target, the target doesnt change.

Comment: @RRikesh : tried with latest version. Still not working.

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing the `$` , with `jQuery` . You usually have to do this in wordpress to avoid conflicts with other plugins/themes/etc using `$` for something else.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#box").draggable();
jQuery("#target").droppable({
 drop: function( event, ui ) {
   jQuery( this )
      .addClass( "twinkle" ).html("dropped");

  }
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot normally add JavaScript in the WordPress editor because it will strip the JavaScript off.

But there are a few alternatives. From the Codex, there is the [Using JavaScript](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript#JavaScript_in_Posts) article. You could also use shortcodes and custom fields as explained in [this article](http://www.labnol.org/software/javascript-in-wordpress/19396/).